# Earliest unit needed to capture city?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

In Civilization beyond earth what are the units needed to capture the city?

I just started the game all I have are rangers and soldiers which obviously can't capture the city. So I was wondering, what is the earliest soldier you have to unlock to be able to capture the city ?

Comment: Rushing Purity 4 and getting early Battlesuit is a pretty strong strategy especially against AI(because they can take a city in 2 turns and they will destroy enemy units in 1 turn if you get them early enough)

Comment: In the right situations you can conquer a city with any melee unit.  Its usually a good idea to soften a city up first with air, sea, and artillery firepower.  I typically only attack with melee units once I know the assault is nearly unstoppable.  A long retreat will typically mean losses. especially for the units that got in the closest, like melee units.

Answer (score 4):

I've captured a city with the first infantry unit (soldier) you can get.

However it would be best to use other units (especially siege units) to do most of the damage otherwise it would take a lot of the low level units to take a city as you would loose several of them.